# pyspark Change the value of a column before using groupby on that column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have this json data , i want to aggregate on 'timestamp' column on hourly basis while summing up the data in column 'b' & 'a'.

```
{"a":1 , "b":1, "timestamp":"2017-01-26T01:14:55.719214Z"}
{"a":1 , "b":1,"timestamp":"2017-01-26T01:14:55.719214Z"}
{"a":1 , "b":1,"timestamp":"2017-01-26T02:14:55.719214Z"}
{"a":1 , "b":1,"timestamp":"2017-01-26T03:14:55.719214Z"}
```

This is the final output that i want

```
{"a":2 , "b":2, "timestamp":"2017-01-26T01:00:00"}
{"a":1 , "b":1,"timestamp":"2017-01-26T02:00:00"}
{"a":1 , "b":1,"timestamp":"2017-01-26T03:00:00"}
```

This is what i have written so far

```
df = spark.read.json(inputfile)
df2 = df.groupby("timestamp").agg(f.sum(df["a"],f.sum(df["b"])
```

But how should I change the value of 'timestamp' column before using groupby function? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34232633/2708667) may be helpful. It shows how to round the parsed timestamp object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f   

df = spark.read.load(path='file:///home/zht/PycharmProjects/test/disk_file', format='json')
df = df.withColumn('ts', f.to_utc_timestamp(df['timestamp'], 'EST'))
win = f.window(df['ts'], windowDuration='1 hour')
df = df.groupBy(win).agg(f.sum(df['a']).alias('sumA'), f.sum(df['b']).alias('sumB'))
res = df.select(df['window']['start'].alias('start_time'), df['sumA'], df['sumB'])
res.show(truncate=False)

# output:
+---------------------+----+----+                                               
|start_time           |sumA|sumB|
+---------------------+----+----+
|2017-01-26 15:00:00.0|1   |1   |
|2017-01-26 16:00:00.0|1   |1   |
|2017-01-26 14:00:00.0|2   |2   |
+---------------------+----+----+
```

**f.window** is much more flexible

Comment: Thanks for the answer , Actually i only need '2017-01-26 15:00:00.0' in timestamp column instead of '[2017-01-26 15:00:00.0,2017-01-26 16:00:00.0]'. Do you know how can i get this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the one way to do this

```
df2 = df.withColumn("r_timestamp",df["r_timestamp"].substr(0,12)).groupby("timestamp").agg(f.sum(df["a"],f.sum(df["b"])
```

Is there any better solution to get the timestamp in the required format?