Pandas on Spark Resample: "Rule Code Not Supported" & "TypeError: Type datetime64[us] was not understood"
I'm trying to do something straightforward in Pandas -- take some time series data and resample it to a minute. But I'm running into a variety of issues from Spark (I'm new to PySpark so be kind ;) )
I'm doing this via "Pandas on Spark" because pivot operations are not appreciated in Spark.
For example, I currently have something that looks like this:
# spark.version == 3.5.0-amzn-0

df = spark.sql('select * from stream_view;').pandas_api()
# type(df) == <class 'pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame'>

df.head() ==

timestamp                      A        B        C                                                                              
2024-05-03 15:25:27.820        0        0        3
2024-05-03 15:25:40.721        2        0        3
2024-05-03 15:26:17.812        1        1        2
2024-05-03 15:26:50.690        3        1        2
2024-05-03 15:27:17.807        3        0        1


And it needs to be transformed to this:
timestamp                  A        B        C                                                                              
2024-05-03 15:25:00        1        0        3
2024-05-03 15:26:00        2        1        2
2024-05-03 15:27:00        3        0        1

If I were doing this in vanilla pandas I'd simply do df.resample('1min').mean() and call it a day. According to the docs that should be possible in PySpark too, but it is not.
df.resample('min')  # also 1min

# throws this error:

An error was encountered:
rule code min is not supported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1714638802442_0031/container_1714638802442_0031_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/pandas/frame.py", line 13373, in resample
    return DataFrameResampler(
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1714638802442_0031/container_1714638802442_0031_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/pandas/resample.py", line 736, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1714638802442_0031/container_1714638802442_0031_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/pandas/resample.py", line 107, in __init__
    raise ValueError("rule code {} is not supported".format(self._offset.rule_code))
ValueError: rule code min is not supported

I also tried different valid rule codes (s, h, etc), but none work (verified in the source code).
Because I originally misunderstood the error message and thought it was something to do with a floor operation, I tried doing that manually. This opened up new issues.
# type(df.index) == <class 'pyspark.pandas.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>

df.index.floor('s')

# but then get this error:

An error was encountered:

  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1714638802442_0031/container_1714638802442_0031_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/pandas/accessors.py", line 955, in pudf
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1714638802442_0031/container_1714638802442_0031_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/pandas/groupby.py", line 2302, in rename_output
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1714638802442_0031/container_1714638802442_0031_01_000004/pyspark.zip/pyspark/pandas/internal.py", line 1629, in prepare_pandas_frame
    spark_type = infer_pd_series_spark_type(reset_index[col], dtype, prefer_timestamp_ntz)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1714638802442_0031/container_1714638802442_0031_01_000004/pyspark.zip/pyspark/pandas/typedef/typehints.py", line 368, in infer_pd_series_spark_type
    return as_spark_type(dtype, prefer_timestamp_ntz=prefer_timestamp_ntz)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1714638802442_0031/container_1714638802442_0031_01_000004/pyspark.zip/pyspark/pandas/typedef/typehints.py", line 248, in as_spark_type
    raise TypeError("Type %s was not understood." % tpe)
TypeError: Type datetime64[us] was not understood.

I tried doing this immediately after converting it from a Spark DF to a Pandas on Spark DF and got the same error, so it's not something that I'm doing to the index's type.
I also tried df.index.round() and that too had the same issue.
Is this API super buggy or am I doing something very wrong? Probably the latter considering how new I am to PySpark (hopefully). In any case, I would really appreciate the help because I've been fighting this all day.
Thanks in advance :)

You can use date_trunc at minute level  as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34232633/3238085 and then do a groupby on unique minute values.

Thanks for the comment! I know this is an option, but it adds complexity to the pivot (I excluded that here for brevity in an already long question) because it creates duplicates in the index (timestamp). I have other working solutions, I'm just really bothered by the fact that I can't do basic things that both the docs and source code suggest that I can do, and since I'm learning Spark I want to make sure that I'm not fundamentally misunderstanding something.
